# Passing an array of string to SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2014

I want to pass an array of CStrings to a stored procedure. And how can use the array by its indexes? The best case can be sending an array with a dynamic length. But I can work with a fixed length array. I need a C++ sample for calling this stored procedure also.

Comment: You want to look at https://www.codeproject.com/articles/39161/c-and-table-value-parameters

Comment: I am looking for a C++ example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one person's solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278060/sql-server-table-valued-parameters-in-c-oledb-client

Stored procedures use tables not arrays. A table has no implicit ordering nor anything that corresponds to an array index. All rows are treated as a single set. SQL statements address the entire set of rows, or a specified subset. Whatever you need to achieve by itterating through the array will be better done set-wise once inside the SP.